# Openshift Django - Can you use a different directory than wsgi/static?

Tags: django, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a Django application in a restricted OpenShift environment, which requires that static files be placed in `wsgi/public/static`. However, I did a ton of research, and believe they must be put in `wsgi/static`.

Is it possible to change this directory?

Unfortunately, the environment only white-lists `/public` to be accessible, all other URLs will get redirected to a SSO login on another domain, therefore I don't think you can use a simple URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in django to put your files inside particular directory, it can be put anywhere in your filesystem if you have permissions and it won't collide with something else.

Remember that this directory is for **collected** static files, you won't keep that directory in your GIT repository. Static files that are servet with your project should be put inside other directory and you should copy or link them into dir with collected static files using `./manage.py collectstatic`.

It's done this way in django because each reusable app can provide it's own set of static files and all of them must be somehow served from one location, so they will be copied or linked into directory with collected files.

So your configuration in django should look like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/wsgi/public/static'
STATIC_URL = '/public/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), # or other path in your project, not necessary defined using BASE_DIR, but it is good approach
)
```

All your static files should go into static in `BASE_DIR` and should be collected after changes using `./manage.py collectstatic`